# Add custom fields to nav-menu item

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add custom data to my menu items (say, for example, `data-*` attributes) or a dropdown to select the link `target`, etc.

Through the Screen Options, we have Link Target, Title Attribute, CSS Classes, Link Relationship (XFN) and Description (see screenshot below), but none really offer what I want.

[image: Default menu item fields]

I thought of looking for extensions to Advanced Custom Fields, or something of the sort, but I have not seen anything like it, nor anything through my theme functions.php file.

Comment: I had this same issue and I WAS able to find an ACF add-on that enables custom fields for menu items. It is called location-nav-menu-for-acf and can be found here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/location-nav-menu-for-acf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found [a good tutorial with lots of details and explanations](http://www.wpexplorer.com/adding-custom-attributes-to-wordpress-menus/) as to how to achieve this. The article explains how the [WordPress plugin **Sweet Custom Menu**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sweet-custom-menu/) works, and I've been able to add the functionality to my current theme.

As of today, the plugin hasn't been updated in over two years, but it still does what is expected of it.

Comment: I found the HTML breaks with WordPress version 4.8.2. Working on the fix.

Comment: @MohitAneja Good to know someone is working on a fix! However, I've gone out a bit with this and added various options since. If you have a git repo, maybe we could mix our work together.

Comment: the solution was easy enough, I just copied the new from latest WordPress class and got it working. I don't have a repo for this yet but will set it up and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Carbon Fields Framework](https://carbonfields.net/docs/containers-nav-menu/). It provides a custom fields for menu items.

Even if you are using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin, you still can add the plugin since both can work together.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', 'custom_nav_edit_walker',10,2 );
function custom_nav_edit_walker($walker,$menu_id) {
    return 'Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit_Custom';
}

/*
 * Saves new field navmenu
 */
add_action('wp_update_nav_menu_item', 'custom_nav_update',10, 3);
function custom_nav_update($menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args ) {
    if ( is_array($_REQUEST['menu-item-custom']) ) {
        $custom_value = $_REQUEST['menu-item-custom'][$menu_item_db_id];
        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_custom', $custom_value );
    }
}

/*
 * Adds value of new field to Navmenu
 */
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','custom_nav_item' );
function custom_nav_item($menu_item) {
    $menu_item->custom = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_custom', true );
    return $menu_item;
}


class Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit_Custom extends Walker_Nav_Menu  {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {}

        /**
         * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
         *
         * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::end_lvl()
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string $output Passed by reference.
         * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param array  $args   Not used.
         */
         function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {}

        /**
         * Start the element output.
         *
         * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el()
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @global int $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth
         *
         * @param string $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
         * @param object $item   Menu item data object.
         * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param array  $args   Not used.
         * @param int    $id     Not used.
         */
         function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
            global $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth;
            $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth = $depth > $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth ? $depth : $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth;

            ob_start();
            $item_id      = esc_attr( $item->ID );
            $removed_args = array(
                'action',
                'customlink-tab',
                'edit-menu-item',
                'menu-item',
                'page-tab',
                '_wpnonce',
            );

            $original_title = false;
            if ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type ) {
                $original_title = get_term_field( 'name', $item->object_id, $item->object, 'raw' );
                if ( is_wp_error( $original_title ) ) {
                    $original_title = false;
                }
            } elseif ( 'post_type' == $item->type ) {
                $original_object = get_post( $item->object_id );
                $original_title  = get_the_title( $original_object->ID );
            } elseif ( 'post_type_archive' == $item->type ) {
                $original_object = get_post_type_object( $item->object );
                if ( $original_object ) {
                    $original_title = $original_object->labels->archives;
                }
            }

            $classes = array(
                'menu-item menu-item-depth-' . $depth,
                'menu-item-' . esc_attr( $item->object ),
                'menu-item-edit-' . ( ( isset( $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) && $item_id == $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) ? 'active' : 'inactive' ),
            );

            $title = $item->title;

            if ( ! empty( $item->_invalid ) ) {
                $classes[] = 'menu-item-invalid';
                /* translators: %s: title of menu item which is invalid */
                $title = sprintf( __( '%s (Invalid)' ), $item->title );
            } elseif ( isset( $item->post_status ) && 'draft' == $item->post_status ) {
                $classes[] = 'pending';
                /* translators: %s: title of menu item in draft status */
                $title = sprintf( __( '%s (Pending)' ), $item->title );
            }

            $title = ( ! isset( $item->label ) || '' == $item->label ) ? $title : $item->label;

            $submenu_text = '';
            if ( 0 == $depth ) {
                $submenu_text = 'style="display: none;"';
            }

            ?>
            <li id="menu-item-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="<?php echo implode( ' ', $classes ); ?>">
                <div class="menu-item-bar">
                    <div class="menu-item-handle">
                        <span class="item-title"><span class="menu-item-title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></span> <span class="is-submenu" <?php echo $submenu_text; ?>><?php _e( 'sub item' ); ?></span></span>
                        <span class="item-controls">
                            <span class="item-type"><?php echo esc_html( $item->type_label ); ?></span>
                            <span class="item-order hide-if-js">
                                <a href="
                                <?php
                                    echo wp_nonce_url(
                                        add_query_arg(
                                            array(
                                                'action'    => 'move-up-menu-item',
                                                'menu-item' => $item_id,
                                            ),
                                            remove_query_arg( $removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) )
                                        ),
                                        'move-menu_item'
                                    );
                                ?>
                                " class="item-move-up" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Move up' ); ?>">&#8593;</a>
                                |
                                <a href="
                                <?php
                                    echo wp_nonce_url(
                                        add_query_arg(
                                            array(
                                                'action'    => 'move-down-menu-item',
                                                'menu-item' => $item_id,
                                            ),
                                            remove_query_arg( $removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) )
                                        ),
                                        'move-menu_item'
                                    );
                                ?>
                                " class="item-move-down" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Move down' ); ?>">&#8595;</a>
                            </span>
                            <a class="item-edit" id="edit-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" href="
                                                                        <?php
                                                                        echo ( isset( $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) && $item_id == $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) ? admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) : add_query_arg( 'edit-menu-item', $item_id, remove_query_arg( $removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php#menu-item-settings-' . $item_id ) ) );
                                                                        ?>
                            " aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Edit menu item' ); ?>"><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Edit' ); ?></span></a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="menu-item-settings wp-clearfix" id="menu-item-settings-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                    <?php if ( 'custom' == $item->type ) : ?>
                        <p class="field-url description description-wide">
                            <label for="edit-menu-item-url-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                                <?php _e( 'URL' ); ?><br />
                                <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-url-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-url" name="menu-item-url[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->url ); ?>" />
                            </label>
                        </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <p class="description description-wide">
                        <label for="edit-menu-item-title-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                            <?php _e( 'Navigation Label' ); ?><br />
                            <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-title-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat edit-menu-item-title" name="menu-item-title[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->title ); ?>" />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field-title-attribute field-attr-title description description-wide">
                        <label for="edit-menu-item-attr-title-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                            <?php _e( 'Title Attribute' ); ?><br />
                            <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-attr-title-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat edit-menu-item-attr-title" name="menu-item-attr-title[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->post_excerpt ); ?>" />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field-link-target description">
                        <label for="edit-menu-item-target-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="edit-menu-item-target-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" value="_blank" name="menu-item-target[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]"<?php checked( $item->target, '_blank' ); ?> />
                            <?php _e( 'Open link in a new tab' ); ?>
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field-css-classes description description-thin">
                        <label for="edit-menu-item-classes-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                            <?php _e( 'CSS Classes (optional)' ); ?><br />
                            <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-classes-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-classes" name="menu-item-classes[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( implode( ' ', $item->classes ) ); ?>" />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field-xfn description description-thin">
                        <label for="edit-menu-item-xfn-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                            <?php _e( 'Link Relationship (XFN)' ); ?><br />
                            <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-xfn-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-xfn" name="menu-item-xfn[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->xfn ); ?>" />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field-description description description-wide">
                        <label for="edit-menu-item-description-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                            <?php _e( 'Description' ); ?><br />
                            <textarea id="edit-menu-item-description-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat edit-menu-item-description" rows="3" cols="20" name="menu-item-description[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]"><?php echo esc_html( $item->description ); // textarea_escaped ?></textarea>
                            <span class="description"><?php _e( 'The description will be displayed in the menu if the current theme supports it.' ); ?></span>
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field-custom description description-wide">
                        <label for="edit-menu-item-custom-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                            <?php _e( 'Custom' ); ?><br />
                            <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-custom-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-custom" name="menu-item-custom[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->custom ); ?>" />
                        </label>
                    </p>                
                    <fieldset class="field-move hide-if-no-js description description-wide">
                        <span class="field-move-visual-label" aria-hidden="true"><?php _e( 'Move' ); ?></span>
                        <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-up" data-dir="up"><?php _e( 'Up one' ); ?></button>
                        <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-down" data-dir="down"><?php _e( 'Down one' ); ?></button>
                        <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-left" data-dir="left"></button>
                        <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-right" data-dir="right"></button>
                        <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-top" data-dir="top"><?php _e( 'To the top' ); ?></button>
                    </fieldset>

                    <div class="menu-item-actions description-wide submitbox">
                        <?php if ( 'custom' != $item->type && $original_title !== false ) : ?>
                            <p class="link-to-original">
                                <?php
                                /* translators: %s: original title */
                                printf( __( 'Original: %s' ), '<a href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) . '">' . esc_html( $original_title ) . '</a>' );
                                ?>
                            </p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <a class="item-delete submitdelete deletion" id="delete-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" href="
                                                                                            <?php
                                                                                            echo wp_nonce_url(
                                                                                                add_query_arg(
                                                                                                    array(
                                                                                                        'action'    => 'delete-menu-item',
                                                                                                        'menu-item' => $item_id,
                                                                                                    ),
                                                                                                    admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' )
                                                                                                ),
                                                                                                'delete-menu_item_' . $item_id
                                                                                            );
                                                                                            ?>
                        "><?php _e( 'Remove' ); ?></a> <span class="meta-sep hide-if-no-js"> | </span> <a class="item-cancel submitcancel hide-if-no-js" id="cancel-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" href="
                        <?php
                        echo esc_url(
                            add_query_arg(
                                array(
                                    'edit-menu-item' => $item_id,
                                    'cancel'         => time(),
                                ),
                                admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' )
                            )
                        );
                        ?>
                            #menu-item-settings-<?php echo $item_id; ?>"><?php _e( 'Cancel' ); ?></a>
                    </div>

                    <input class="menu-item-data-db-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-db-id[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" />
                    <input class="menu-item-data-object-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-object-id[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->object_id ); ?>" />
                    <input class="menu-item-data-object" type="hidden" name="menu-item-object[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->object ); ?>" />
                    <input class="menu-item-data-parent-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-parent-id[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->menu_item_parent ); ?>" />
                    <input class="menu-item-data-position" type="hidden" name="menu-item-position[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->menu_order ); ?>" />
                    <input class="menu-item-data-type" type="hidden" name="menu-item-type[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->type ); ?>" />
                </div><!-- .menu-item-settings-->
                <ul class="menu-item-transport"></ul>
            <?php
            $output .= ob_get_clean();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this code. Looking at it, it seems to be similar to what I had found way back ([view my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40349413/2748327)).